# How to handle exceptions in python using the `with` statement in python?

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

Assuming this piece of code:

```
connection = get_some_connection() # maybe from oursql
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('some query')
```

I understand that after finishing `cursor.close()` will be executed automatically. What about exceptions? Must I put them inside?

```
connection = get_some_connection() # maybe from oursql
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    try:
        cursor.execute('some query')
    except IntegrityError, e:
        # handle exceoption
```

Or is there a nicer way to handle them with the with statement?

Answer (score 4):

`with x as y: z()` is basically syntactic sugar for:

```
y = x
y.__enter__()
try:
    z()
finally:
    if y.__exit__: y.__exit__()
```

This is not completely accurate, but that's the gist of it.  Note that `__exit__()` will be passed exception information if an exception was thrown (see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typecontextmanager.html)) so you can "handle" an exception this way, but this will not keep the exception from being thrown up the call stack.

If you want to handle the exception gracefully and consume it, you need to use a `try`/`catch` block.  It can be inside the `with` block or outside of it, as long as the try block is active when the exception is raised.

Comment: Because of how the exception propagates, could you not also put the `try`/`catch` immediately **outside** the `with` block? ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the particular case of [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/api.html#cursor-classes),

```
with some_connection.cursor() as cursor:
    do_something_with(cursor)
```

is equivalent to

```
cursor = some_connection.cursor()
try:
    do_something_with(cursor)
except:
    some_connection.rollback()
    raise
else:
    some_connection.commit()
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

As you can see, what a `with` statement does depends on the context manager (e.g. some_connection.cursor()`).

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    try:
        cursor.execute('some query')
    except IntegrityError as e:
        # handle exception
```

may or may not be the correct way to handle an `IntegrityError` -- you might want to handle the IntegrityError in some outer scope.

For example, if you had some generic function which logs queries such as

```
def log_query(query):
    logger.info(query)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)

try:
    log_query(query)
except IntegrityError as err:
     # handler error
```

you may not want to handle `IntegrityError`s inside log_query, but rather at a later stage.

Comment: Note that if you do handle the error internally, and don't re-raise, then you had better handle it in a way that is compatible with the `some_connection.commit()` that happens when the cursor's with-block cleans up :)